# Unexpected jQuery syntax error by chaining a plug-in after .find()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, syntax-error

I've baked a `plug-in` to handle runtime searches on input fields I'm using all over a big site.
The plug-in works perfect in every situation but this http://jsfiddle.net/tonino/v8d2A/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var callback_methods = { /* methods here */ };
    var input_html = '<div class="search"><input name="search-field" value="Search..."></div>';
    $(document).on('click', 'div.add', function (event) {
        if (!$('li div.add + div').hasClass('search')) {
            var input = $(this).after(input_html).parent().find('input');
            input.focus();
            input.hunter({url:'<?php echo $this->request->base; ?>/searches', callback:callback_methods, var_name:'data[Search][term]'});
            // other code after
        }
    });
});​
```

If I comment the hunter plug-in everything works fine.

I'm sure is some concept on how it must be structured, here is the code: [jquery.hunter.1.3.js](http://vittoriovittori.com/file/jquery.hunter.1.3.js)

Why my `plug-in` make this error in this situation, where I'm wrong on writing it?

Comment: Could you show the generated code ?

Comment: sorry it wasn't clear, I've updated the question, I also put the url here  http://jsfiddle.net/tonino/v8d2A/

Comment: No. I meant the error is probably due to the PHP generated code. Can we see the code sent to the browser ? jsFiddle doesn't interpret PHP.

Comment: I don't send the request because the error come when i call the hunter plug-in `input.hunter({url:'<?php echo $this->request->base; ?>/searches', callback:callback_methods, var_name:'data[Search][term]'});` here. to make the request I should write something in the input field, but error come out on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is this part of your code:

```
var selector = this.selector;

var def_css = {backgroundPosition:'-16px center', paddingLeft:$(selector).css('padding-left')}
if (settings.loader) { setStyle(def_css); }
   var selector = this.selector;
```

and later:

```
$(this.selector).blur(function () {
```

first of all your code wont work when the if-condition is fulfilled, because you are trying to redeclare the variable 'selector' inside the if block. just leave the var-statement out there:

```
if (settings.loader) { setStyle(def_css); }
  selector = this.selector;
```

but YOUR MAIN-problem is that 'this.selector' contains '.parent() input' which i doubt is a valid jQuery selector.

why are you doing that? why dont you just use $(this) save it into a variable and use this???

eg:

```
// first line in your plugin
$this = $(this) 


// later you could use the $this var
$this.blur(function () {
```

Comment: because I'm wrong `:)` I'll fix it and let you know if it works.

Comment: updated the fiddle (added the plugin-code inside), see here: http://jsfiddle.net/v8d2A/18/

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the error change this line:

```
var input = $(this).after(input_html).parent().find('input');
```

To the following:

```
var input = $(input_html).insertAfter($(this));
```

The core problem though is that the `jquery.hunter` plugin is using the `this.selector` variable for some reason - you don't need this - the plugin should use `$(this)` instead of `$(this.selector)`